# How do I prevent editor from adding new line after opening bracket of JSON object?

Tags: pycharm

In a recent version of OS X PyCharm, the Javascript editor started forcing
a new line after opening bracket to a JSON object when typing the closing
bracket. How do I disable the new line insertion? I can't figure it out in
the Preferences.

1) Before typing closing bracket

[image: Before typing closing bracket]

2) After typing closing bracket

[image: After typing closing bracket]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the code is auto-formatted when you type the closing bracket - that's the issue. Unfortunately this feature can't be turned off (please vote for [IDEA-122075](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122075))
And there is currently no option to keep the opening bracket on the same line as a square bracket - see [WEB-7226](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7226)

Comment: Thanks Lena for the answer. I hope they fix this soon.